# SDO_GEOMETRY uniqueness in Oracle

Tags: oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

Is it feasible converting the spatial property (SDO_GEOMETRY) of a table in Oracle as an unique index or spatial constraint for avoiding spatial duplicates?

I am working on point tables and I don't want having spatial duplicates, I mean two points for the same location.

Comment: I'd expect that eliminating the possibility coincident points would be exceedingly difficult through a spatial index.

Comment: You want to prevent inserting duplicates? What if you create a trigger that takes GEOMETRY.SDO_POINT.X GEOMETRY.SDO_POINT.Y and tries to insert them concatenated into a column with unique index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has several possible answers:

1) If you are looking only at avoid getting duplicate **points** into your table - and that means points with **exactly** the same coordinates, down to all possible decimals, **and** the points are using the SDO_POINT_TYPE construct, then yes, indeed, you can just define a unique index on the X and Y properties:

```
create unique index us_cities_unique on us_cities (location.sdo_point.x, location.sdo_point.y);
```

(This assuming that table US_CITIES has a column called LOCATION).

Then when you try and insert an object with the exact same coordinates as an existing one, you get the proper failure:

```
SQL> insert into us_cities (id, location) select 10001,location from us_cities where id=1;
insert into us_cities (id, location) select 10001,location from us_cities where id=1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.US_CITIES_UNIQUE) violated
```

2) If on the other hand you want to avoid storing points with coordinates that can be **slightly different** but still point to the same location (= the two points are separated by just a few centimeters for example) **or** your shapes store the point coordinates in the SDO_ORDINATES structure **or** you want to generalize the problem of avoiding duplicate shapes to **any** shape (not just 2D or 3D points), then the problem becomes more complicated as well as more interesting.

One possible approach then is to use a trigger that will run an SDO_EQUAL search to locate any existing identical shape in your table and throw an exception (= RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR) if it finds one. That is a bit more complicated than it sounds due to the restrictions in Oracle of reading from the triggering table inside a trigger (= the "mutating table" problem) so you need a bit of thinking to write that trigger properly.

And of course, this trigger will obviously have performance implications, since each and every insert (or update) in that table will force a spatial query on the table. Guaranteeing data quality comes at a cost.

3) If you have an **existing table** with duplicates and you want to detect and remove those, then your best approach is to use the **SDO_JOIN** technique to discover (and subsequently remove them).

Note that blindly removing duplicates may not be trivial: should you have three different objects with the same geometry (but different attributes) which one should you keep ? That requires additional logic.

Comment: thanks, by the way I keep the non-spatial attributes in a separate table, so option 3 doesn't apply in my case..And option 2 either because my table is free of duplicates so far. I will go for option 1.